# C++ COORD error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I'm currently trying to create a Tetris game and when I call this:

```
void PrintChar(int x, int y, char ch, Colors color) {
    COORD c = { y,x };

    FillConsoleOutputCharacterW(GameData::handle, ch, 1, c, NULL);
    FillConsoleOutputAttribute(GameData::handle, color, 1, c, NULL);
}
```

this Warning comes up:

> C4838 - conversion from 'int' to 'SHORT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion.

Could someone please explain what is happening here and a small example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The warning should be pretty clear if you know what the context of `COORD` is (we don't).

Comment: would it be acceptable to write 'COORD c = {(short)x, (short)y};' ??

Comment: What's `COORD` actually?

Comment: Apparently it's some [MS screen buffer structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682119(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: typedef struct _COORD {
    SHORT X;
    SHORT Y;
} COORD, *PCOORD;

Comment: @RelientFX So may be casting could help, yes.

Comment: Don't add relevant information in comments. Instead, [edit] your question and include it there instead, where it can be seen.

Comment: Unrelated: why are you flipping `x` and `y`?

Comment: The warning is telling you the conversion (int -> short) may lead to data loss. If you are ok with that, cast away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use explicit typecast

```
COORD c = { static_cast<short>(x), static_cast<short>(y) };
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using [copy-list-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), a language feature introduced in C++11, that prevents implicit (potentially) lossy conversions. In a C++11-compliant compiler, this construct should really produce an [error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77449ebb4e53f115) (not just a warning)<sup>1</sup>.

One possible solution is to use a `static_cast` (with direct-list-initialization as a bonus), if you know that the input will never overflow the range of the destination type:

```
COORD c{ static_cast<SHORT>( x ), static_cast<SHORT>( y ) };
```

---

<sup>1</sup> *Visual Studio issues a [warning C4838](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt763968.aspx), in case there is a potentially lossy narrowing conversion, that cannot be evaluated at compile time. If a narrowing conversion of a constant expression does cause loss of information, [error C2397](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt763946.aspx) is issued instead. I don't know whether this is compliant with C++11 and C++14, though.*